# Flutter SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle transparent statusBar isn't working

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I run this at the begining of the app before the runApp():

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Everything works as expected. The StatusBar color is white with dark icons.

However, I'm not able to create a StatusBar with transparent background color, which will change based on the screen colors.

When I change the statusBar color to transparent, it just gets to normal.

[image]

How can I make a dynamic statusBar background?